# How to keep drawn shapes from disappearing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm working on a project to create a screen saver that draws random shapes. I have a few questions, but my main concern right now is how to get the shapes to stay on the screen and not just disappear after they are created. Here is my code. I cannot use any loops and I am not looking to change any of the functionality of what I have yet (other than possibly shapesDrawn).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ScreenSaver2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("FullSize");
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    boolean full;


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int r = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int gr = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int b = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        Color color = new Color(r, gr, b);
        int width = 10 + (int)(Math.random() * 40);
        int height = 10 + (int)(Math.random() * 40);
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * (getWidth() - width));
        int y = (int)(Math.random() * (getHeight() - height));
        int whichShape = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
        int shapesDrawn = 0;

        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (shapesDrawn >= 30) {
            shapesDrawn = 0;
        }

        switch (whichShape) {
        case 0:
            g.setColor(color);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 1:
            g.setColor(color);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 2:
            g.setColor(color);
            g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 25, 25);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 3:
            g.setColor(color);
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        }

    }


    ScreenSaver2() {
        // Remove the title bar, min, max, close stuff
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        // Add a Key Listener to the frame
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        // Add this panel object to the frame
        frame.add(this);
        // Get the dimensions of the screen
        rectangle = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
        .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        // Set the size of the frame to the size of the screen
        frame.setSize(rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Remember that we are currently at full size
        full = true;
        // set and initialize timer
        Timer t = new Timer(500, this);
        t.setDelay(500);
        t.start();

    }

    // This method will run when any key is pressed in the window
    class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // Terminate the program.
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'x') {
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            // Change background color
            else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'r') {
                System.out.println("Change background color");
                setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256)));
                repaint();
            }
            // Resize to half-screen
            else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'z') {
                System.out.println("Resizing");
                frame.setSize((int)rectangle.getWidth() / 2, (int)rectangle.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScreenSaver2 obj = new ScreenSaver2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use loops?

Comment: @nhgrif It's a restriction of the stupid assignment :P

Comment: you are continuously calling repaint() with random  shape, yet you want to keep the old paint. ~^

Comment: something like 
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (shapesDrawn >= 30) {
  shapesDrawn = 0;
  repaint();
 }

Comment: @Ryel, FWIW you should have your prof take a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the normal way to do something like this. These examples should be modified to have an "addShape()" method which would either add a Shape to the ArrayList or paint the Shape on the BufferedImage. Then your Timer would just invoke the addShape() method with a new shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than painting each new shape within the `paintComponent` directly to the `Graphics` context, use a backing buffer to render the shapes to first and paint this to the `Graphics` context.

This way, you would simply need to maintain a simple counter each time a new shape is rendered.

This is also troublesome, because `paintComponent` may be called for any number of reasons, which, you don't control many, meaning that it would be possible for your program to paint more shapes before any timer ticks have actually occurred...

**Updated with example**

The only choice you have left is to create a backing buffer, onto which you can paint each change as required.  This will "store" each change between paint cycles.  You could then simply paint this to the screen...

```
private BufferedImage img;

//...

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    // Create the backing buffer
    // This is a little cheat, creating a new image when the number of shapes
    // exceeds the requirements, but it saves messing about with clearing
    // a alpha image ;)
    if (img == null || shapesDrawn >= 30) {
        img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        shapesDrawn = 0;
    } else if (img.getWidth() != getWidth() || img.getHeight() != img.getHeight()) {
        // Update the backing buffer to meet the requirements of the changed screen size...
        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gbuffer = buffer.createGraphics();
        gbuffer.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        gbuffer.dispose();
        img = buffer;
    }

    // Get a reference to the backing buffers graphics context...
    Graphics2D gbuffer = img.createGraphics();

    // Paint the shapes to the backing buffer...
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int gr = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color color = new Color(r, gr, b);
    int width = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 40);
    int height = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 40);
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() - width));
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() - height));
    int whichShape = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    int shapesDrawn = 0;

    switch (whichShape) {
        case 0:
            gbuffer.setColor(color);
            gbuffer.drawLine(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 1:
            gbuffer.setColor(color);
            gbuffer.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 2:
            gbuffer.setColor(color);
            gbuffer.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 25, 25);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
        case 3:
            gbuffer.setColor(color);
            gbuffer.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            shapesDrawn++;
            break;
    }
    // Dispose of the buffers graphics context, this frees up memory for us
    gbuffer.dispose();
    // Paint the image to the screen...
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

**Possibly the worst advice I've ever had to give**

Change...

```
super.paintComponent(g);
if (shapesDrawn >= 30) {
    shapesDrawn = 0;
}
```

To...

```
if (shapesDrawn >= 30) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    shapesDrawn = 0;
}
```

Comment: I spoke with my professor this morning and he specifically said to move everything into the paintComponent. It is working, but the shapes won't stay on the screen which means I don't know if the counter is working.

Comment: also @MadProgrammer it was frustrating because I basically had to trash everything you helped me with lol

Comment: Every time `paintComponent` is called, it will clear the graphics context, this is the expected functionality.  With out a loop, the only choice you have is to paint the output to a backing buffer first before painting it to the screen...

Comment: Oh do you mean to draw the shapes, and number them and then initialize the switch component?

Comment: I would also add  in addition to @MadProgrammer 's comments even if the program worked, doing all the drawing in `paintComponent` in general is a bad idea since it blocks doing computation. In this case your painting probably isn't enough to notice much.  It's much better to update a separate buffer object and then only have a few lines of code in `paintComponent` that copies the buffer to the paint `Graphcis` object.

Comment: @madProgrammer, I wonder whither Reyl got the mentioned 'back buffer'. uhh, you added an example. He should get it now

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is what I was told after I showed him ScreenSaver1.

Comment: You MUST get rid of the loop... and of the arrayList for that matter.The actionListener should just contain the call to repaint.start the timer in the constructor one time and thats it.move all the code about drawing random shapes into the paintcomponent method.When you decide what shape you want to draw, just draw it! Dont put it into an array.and finally, in the paintcomponent method, just call super.paintComponent when you have reached 30 shapes drawn. Instead of using shapes.size to count with, just add a count member variable and whenever paintComponent is called increment it

Comment: *"You MUST.."*  What?  Who 'you'?  Are you channeling the mad professor?

Comment: @Ryel That is possibly some of the stupidest advice I've ever heard.  The `Graphics` context is a shared resource, meaning that anything that was painted before you component will still be "visible" on it, that's the point of calling `super.paintComponent`.  I don't care if there is nothing else on the screen, this is encouraging bad practices that will turn around and bite you on the rear end quicker than you can blink - Take it from someone who's being coding with swing professional for more than 14 years ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I get that, but like I told you the other night, it is just to stress what we've learned in lessons this week. I understand what you are telling me to do, but it won't meet his criteria. What I have set up so far is within "His" bounds, but I can't figure out how to get the shapes to not repaint() without causing the timer to not work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know that you hate this code, but I knew it was something that simple. That is what happens when you are a noob like me.

Comment: @Ryel That's why the recommendation is so scary.

Comment: I see what you are saying because now the 'r' command to change background color is broken.

Comment: Yep, now you can't change the background without wiping out what you have previously painted.  You said this was new course at your school?  You need a new teacher :P

Comment: You could always provide the teacher with my solution, listing all the reasons why you were forced to use it ;)

Comment: I provided the solution and that is what he told me to do. I have to admit this is the worst class I've ever taken and luckily I'm not studying to become a programmer. I even told him that I spent more time studying on Oracle.com and here, but he didn't seem to care.

Comment: Is there any way to get 'r' to work without changing too much else?